# Multiset image of a set under a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, terminology, group-homomorphism, multisets

I know the basic group theory definition of the *image* of a subset of group elements under a homomorphism is the following:

> The image of any subset $X \subseteq G$ is given by $\phi(X) = \{\phi(x) : x \in X\}$, and we denote $\phi(G)$ by $\text{im}\phi$.

I'm currently interested in modifying this definition to consider the "multiset image", because I want to maintain the cardinality of the set even once it's transformed under homorphism. So, for example, if we have the set $X = \{0, 1, 5\}$ in $(\mathbb Z_8, +)$, and the homomorphism $f(x) = x \;\text{mod}\; 2$, then the image by the above definition would be $\{0, 1\}$ because both 1 and 5 map to 1 so we get some amount of "collapse". I'd like to have a different definition where the image is just: $\{0, 1, 1\}$, something like:

> The multiset image of any subset $X \subseteq G$ is given by the multiset $[\phi(x) : x \in X]$

so that we can allow the duplicate elements. My question is whether this notion has a name and has been studied in group theory literature. I've tried searching for "multiset image" + "homomorphism" and struggling to turn up anything, but I'd be quite surprised if this isn't a thing?

Any links to papers or better definitions/terminology than mine would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The first definition is valid irrespective of $\phi$ being a homomorphism. It holds for every *map* $\phi$.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo Yes, I guess the question as a whole makes sense to ask about general maps - I just happened to be working with group homomorphism in the context where this arose.

Comment: I don't know if it has a name, but it makes perfectly good sense. If you plan to use this in written work, then you should introduce a new notation - I don't know of any standard notation for this. The Magma system uses $\{*\,\,\,*\}$, for example $\{* \,1,2,3,3,4,4,4\, *\}$.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to proceed would be to identify your subset $X$ of $G$ with the element $\sum_{g \in X} g$ of the [group algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring) ${\Bbb Z}[G]$. The elements of $\Bbb Z[G]$ are written as formal sums
$\sum_{g \in G} c_g g$, with $c_g \in \Bbb Z$ for all $g \in G$.
Now a group morphism $\varphi: G \to H$ induces a $\Bbb Z$-algebra morphism and then $\varphi(X)$ would be $\sum_{x \in X}\varphi(x)$.

In your case, you would have $G = {\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z}$, $H = {\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z}$ and $\varphi: G \to H$ defined by $\varphi(1) = 1$. Underlying the elements of $G$ and $H$ to avoid confusion,
$X$ would be $\underline{0} + \underline{1} + \underline{5}$ and $\varphi(X)$ would be $\underline{0} + \underline{1} + \underline{1} = \underline{0} + 2\cdot \underline{1}$.